# How to get the sum 30 by choosing 3 numbers from these sequence?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence

I have a sequence of numbers - 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15 
I want to get the sum 30 by choosing 3 numbers from this sequence of numbers .
The numbers can be repeated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my choice is

> 11+13+3! = 11+13+6 =30

Answer (score 0):

As all these numbers are odd, the sum of three of them is odd as well.
Is this a lateral-thinking puzzle?
For example,

> do some of the commas represent decimal points? 1.3+5.7=7, or with some similar trick we may achieve the sum of two being odd.

Comment: ya it is kind of lateral thinking!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible tweaks for this well known question

One of them Could be

> 11 + 3! + 13 = 30

or

> ()+15+15

Answer (score 0):

As adding three odd numbers would never give an even number...there must be a trick...

hence this is my best guess.

> 3!+9+15=30

Answer (score 0):

Also possible to do it these ways:

> 3*7 + 9

or

> 3*5 + 15